# autoload data to extjs window

Tags: extjs, window

I create Ext.window with two textBox `T1`, `T2`. `T1` has property `id` set to `id`. `T2` has property `id` set to `name`. When this window will be showed I want to this window get value for that textbox from aspx file

When I create Ext.Window I set property:

```
autoLoad: {
    url: somePath + 'App_Modify.aspx',
    params: {
         rek_id: 'someValue'
    }
}
```

In `somePath + 'App_Modify.aspx'` I return json, ex. { id: 3, name: 'xz' }. I thought this value would be automatically set to textBox `T1` and `T2`, but instead of this json text show on my window and textbox disappeared..

I don't know if I do some error or I don't understand how work `autoLoad`. Please for some help explanation

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are assigning the value in your textboxes, it isn't in your code snippet. Also I don't recommend using the 'id' property that way much better to use ['itemId'](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId). But based on what you say in your question this should work:

```
autoLoad: {
    url: somePath + 'App_Modify.aspx',
    params: {
         rek_id: 'someValue'
    },
    callback: function(records) {
        Ext.getCmp('id').setValue(records[0].get('id'));
        Ext.getCmp('name').setValue(records[0].get('name'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just think that if in json respone will be `{ id: 3, name: 'xz' }` that value `3` will be assign to textBox which property id is set to `id` and value `xz` will be assign to textBox which property id is set to `name`. I saw somewhere solution which can automatically assign values from respone to components in extjs. But I don't remember how can I go it

Comment: I haven't seen that but it sounds useful, please update if you find it again.